# How to control realistic car controller when it is in the air in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, controls, game-physics

I am using RCC car controller to make a car stunt game. There are different types of ramps that I am using for stunt. But I am facing some issue while driving the car. Here are some issue and I need your help.

- When I jump from the ramp then my car goes into air and I become out of controls. How can I control it while in the air (I just need to move the car left or right to land on surface)
- How can I make my car have good grip on the surface? (When I drive the car on circle type ramps and my car goes down) I want to move the car in the circle. Here I circle type ramp image.

[image]

I have searched a lot of even read the documentation but did not find any solution.

Comment: If you want to control the car mid-air then "realistic" probably isn't what you really want... not unless your car has jet boosters...

Comment: Seeing your current car controller script would be immensely helpful. Cars in real life loose all control when in the air. Games typically let you generate torque out of no where to allow you to rotate the car for landing. In regards to the loop it is probably the wrong size or you're traveling way too slow. You could improve your chances a bit by adding some downforce (F1 cars make that with their front and rear wings). I would recommend something that pulls in the direction of the tracks normal.